# Express React Socket.io Compilation Error

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm building a web single-page app with react that connects with my express backend using a socket.io websocket. I checked that the socket.io script is being loaded right in my index.html file. I've also declared a variable named socket in the same place to make the socket accessible from the react component scripts. The intent is to use this variable inside my react components. But jsx compiler says:

```
9:2  error  'socket' is not defined  no-undef
```

If I check the 'socket' var at chrome console everything looks right. I guess that this var should be defined at compile time, but how?

Here goes the react component code.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    
        socket.on('hello', function(){
                console.log('YAY!');
        })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here goes my index.html code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    
    <title>React App</title>
    
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001')
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It needs to be visible in your react module.

Answer (score 1):

first install socket.io like this:

```
npm install socket.io --save
```

then you should import socket.io as a module just like you did with react:

```
import socket from 'socket.io'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution here.**

1. Remove all the socket.io scripts on index.html
2. Import the right module in your component:

   ```
   import io from 'socket.io-client';
   ```
3. Use it this way:

   ```
   componentWillMount(){

     this.socket = io('http://localhost:3001');

     this.socket.on('hello', function(){
       console.log('YAY!');
     })

   }
   ```

Full code:

(index.html)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    
    <title>React App</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

React Component (App.js)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

class App extends Component {

  
  componentWillMount(){

    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3001');

   this.socket.on('hello', function(){
    console.log('YAY!');
   })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to Riact</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```